# Does homosexuality go against the fitra according to the Qur'an and Sunnah?

Tags: homosexuality, fitrah

[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/10050) write:

> They (gays and lesbians) both go against the natural disposition (fitrah) which Allaah has created in mankind – and also in animals – whereby the male is inclined towards the female, and vice versa.

A similar claim is made by [Muslim Matters](http://muslimmatters.org/2009/04/13/dealing-with-homosexual-urges/), and it can be found in online forums by searching.

**Question**: Does homosexuality go against the fitra according to the Qur'an and Sunnah?

While the Islam Q&A fatwa quotes the Qur'an and Sunnah, there isn't (or, perhaps more accurately, I didn't recognize) an explicit reference which shows that homosexuality go against fitra.

Comment: Maybe a more general question: what exactly is "fitrah"? There'll be scholars who say fitrah is supposed to be an inborn inclination towards Islam and what it commands, others may have interpretations along the line of "whatever you are born with". Clarifying that would probably clear up a lot of questions around the nexus "I'm involuntarily inclined to do X, is this against fitrah". Unless you'd like to generalize your question to this, I'll post it in a couple days.

Comment: Yes because in the Qu'ran it says:“It is He who created you from a single soul, And made its mate of like nature in order that you might dwell with her in love....” (7:189)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, it does go against the *Fitrah*

We know this because the warning against homosexuality was central to Prophet Lut's mission:

> أَتَأْتُونَ الذُّكْرَانَ مِنَ الْعَالَمِينَ وَتَذَرُونَ مَا خَلَقَ لَكُمْ رَبُّكُم مِّنْ أَزْوَاجِكُم  بَلْ أَنتُمْ قَوْمٌ عَادُونَ
>   Do you go in unto the males of the world, and leave those whom Allah has created for you to be your wives? Nay, you are a trespassing people!"
>
> [Surah Ash-Shu'araa, Verses 165-166](http://tanzil.net/#26:165)

These verses show that Prophet Lut explained to his people why the act of homosexuality is an unnatural one - that they chose to leave what Allah naturally ordained for them as wives.

Comment: You’re confusing the terms. Any sin is a trespassing. That doesn’t mean that every sin goes against the natural state of the human.

Answer (score 2):

**Allah's fitrah on intimate relationships between humans**

Allah explained His fitrah on the matter in several verses:

- > It is He who created you from one soul and created from it its mate that he might dwell in security with her. And when he covers her, she carries a light burden and continues therein. And when it becomes heavy, they both invoke Allah , their Lord, "If You should give us a good [child], we will surely be among the grateful." ([7:189](https://legacy.quran.com/7/189))

  Which was quoted by @Armaan in the comment, and was the first verse that came to mind when reading this question.
- > And of His signs is that He created for you from yourselves mates that you may find tranquillity in them; and He placed between you affection and mercy. Indeed in that are signs for a people who give thought. ([30:21](https://legacy.quran.com/30/21))

Both verses actually say that the pure nature (fitrah) which was given all humans at their birth is that of having a mate of the opposite gender (later). And which leads to off-spring.
Beside this all rulings related to a an intimate relationship in the Qur'an addresses the relations between partners/mates of both  or more precisely opposite genders.

**Some evidences for homosexuality being against the fitrah according the Qur'an**

And Allah () in the Qur'an clearly condemns homosexuality or the doing of the people of Luth -which actually leads to the conclusion that it must be against the fitrah:

- > And [We had sent] Lot when he said to his people, "Do you commit such immorality as no one has preceded you with from among the worlds? (80)
  >   Indeed, you approach men with desire, instead of women. Rather, you are a transgressing people." ([7:80-81](https://legacy.quran.com/7/80-81))

  This verse moreover leads to the conclusion that none committed before the people of Sodom (people of Luth) so it must be against the fitrah.
- > Do you approach males among the worlds (165)
  >   And leave what your Lord has created for you as mates? But you are a people transgressing." ([26:165-166](https://legacy.quran.com/26/165-166))

Here the Luth actually point at the mismatch between Allah's fitrah and the practice of the people of Sodom.

- > And [mention] Lot, when he said to his people, "Do you commit immorality while you are seeing? (54)
  >   Do you indeed approach men with desire instead of women? Rather, you are a people behaving ignorantly." ([27:54-55](https://legacy.quran.com/27/54-55))

  Here the Qur'an calls it immorality, and we know that Allah doesn't forbids immorality so how would he make it a part of the pure nature (fitrah) (see for example [16:90](https://legacy.quran.com/16/90)) in opposition to what Satan orders (see for example [24:21](https://legacy.quran.com/24/21)).
- > And [mention] Lot, when he said to his people, "Indeed, you commit such immorality as no one has preceded you with from among the worlds. (28)
  >   Indeed, you approach men and obstruct the road and commit in your meetings [every] evil." And the answer of his people was not but they said, "Bring us the punishment of Allah , if you should be of the truthful." ([29:28-29](https://legacy.quran.com/29/28-29))

  The first of the quoted verses again states that the people of Luth were the innovators or initiators of this immorality, while the second one points at the mismatch with the fitrah.

Also note that Luth tried to convince them by even offering his own daughters for marriage as stated in several verses.

So a part of the kufr (disbelieve) of the people of Luth was their rejection to live according Allahs rules and his fitrah.