# Is there anything in Islam about homosexuality in animals?

Tags: homosexuality, animals

I am a biologist working with different animal species, especially social species, who usually have homosexual behaviors--for example, to show social status or to raise one's offspring together. I am also a Muslim and **I wanted to know if there was anything on this topic in Islam**.
Homosexuality is considered an "abomination" in our religion so why can it be seen in animals? I know that humans and non-human animals do not have the same "rules" in Islam, but how can it be forbidden when it seems so... natural, in social species (humans being one too)?

Please note that my question is totally serious and sincere and that I do not say that forbidding homosexuality is unfair: I am only looking for information. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe because we are not like animals?

Comment: It also ties into the fact, that not everything that is natural is moral. A lot of things that happen naturally fail most conventional morality of today. For example, Hanuman langurs commit infanticide. Natural for that species but still forbidden to us.

Answer (score 8):

Cannibalism and other humanely-perceived heinous acts can be found in the animal world. Just because an act can be found in the natural world does not justify humans to act upon it as well.

Just because a female scorpion kills its male counterpart after mating does not justify a female murdering her husband after mating with him.

In conclusion, "natural animal" acts are not an argument against Islam's stance on homosexual act.

Comment: i spent a good hour imagining what the world could be if we followed "animal acts"

Comment: quran.com/36/36 is verese  about pairs.

Comment: "Just because an act can be found in the natural world does not justify humans to act upon it as well." No, but it is proof that those are natural behaviors, which contradicts the claim that homosexuality is against fitrah, which makes those observations evidence against Islamic doctrine on homosexuality.

Comment: @G.Bach What evidence suggests that homosexuality is against fitrah? Zina is also part of the natural world, yet it’s forbidden. Fitrah doesn’t seem to hold power over what it legal and what isn’t. (If you are defining Fitrah as Natural)

Comment: See [this thread that is about whether homosexuality is against fitrah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/38974/does-homosexuality-go-against-the-fitra-according-to-the-quran-and-sunnah). See also [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/39162/17702).

Comment: @G. Bach It’s a mistake. The evidence brought forth doesn’t talk about fitrah. It just says that Homosexuality is forbidden. But I understand where you’re coming from, far too many speakers keep saying it’s against fitrah. This has no Islamic basis I’m afraid.

Comment: @Shadi If you have a better answer to my question (second link in last comment), I'd be interested to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in surah al Ankabut verse (28-29) it has been said-

(Wa Lootan iz qaala liqawmiheee innakum laatoonal faahishata maa sabaqakum bihaa min ahadim minal 'aalameen)

Meaning:And [mention] Lot, when he said to his people, "Indeed, you commit such immorality as no one has preceded you with from among the worlds.(Sahih International)

"And Lot, when he said to his people 'Surely you commit such indecency as never any being in all the world committed before you."(Translated by A. J. Arberry)

"And Lot: when He said to his people, ‘You practise outrageous acts that no people before you have ever committed."(Translated by Abdul Haleem)

ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ- means "worlds". So it can be total living being on earth or also can count being outside the earth.

Information are from: https://qurano.com/en/29-al-ankabut/verse-28/

May Allah forgive me if I misinterpret anything here.
Allah knows the best.

Well I have a question here:
Is it possible for those animals to follow such illegal act of human?[Allah knows the best]

Assalamu Alaikum